# Can a constant in properties file be broke in many lines not just 1 line (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

in properties file you can have a very long constant like this

```
errMessage=This is error.........very long sentence ......
```

This is very hard to manage, so i tried to break the long sentence into many lines like this

```
errMessage=This is error.........very
 long sentence ......
```

However, i got runtime error. So my question is "is there any way to "break the long constants" in properties file in GWT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like [any properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29), you can end a line in `\` to make multi line. Or you can put a `\n` in your value to insert a new line:

```
foo=first line\
 second line
bar=first line\nsecond line
```